# I can't open modal from php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, modal-dialog, materialize

I have a code by using Materializecss and PHP. I want to open some modal by returning Php code. For example code is 4  is equal wrong password etc.

But I never satisfied to show modal even try several suggestions shown on this site.

Can you help me?

Here is part of my code :

```
<?php
....
else {
    echo "<script>$('#modalWrongPassword').fadeIn('show');</script>";
}
}               
?>
...
<div id="modalWrongPassword" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <h4>Hatalı şifre</h4>
        <p>A bunch of text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="#!" class=" modal-action modal-close waves-effect        waves-green btn-flat">Kapat</a>
    </div>
</div>
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/jquery-2.js"></script>
<script>if (!window.jQuery) { document.write('<script src="bin/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"><\/script>'); }</script>
<script src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="../js/prism.js"></script>
<script src="../js/lunr.js"></script>
<script src="../js/materialize1.js"></script>
<script src="../js/init1.js"></script> 
...
```

Comment: Then you should look into the PHP `if / else` condition may be something wrong there and make sure the modal script is DOM ready, Note: you don't need to post your reply as answer, you can simply add reply as comment here

Comment: if and else condition workd. Because I can get echo message for this conditions. But cant show modal. Screen turns semi black. But modal windows not shown

Comment: make it DOM ready solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Materializecss, can't open a modal like the way you are trying

```
echo "<script>$('#modalWrongPassword').fadeIn('show');</script>";
```

Here is the [reference](http://materializecss.com/modals.html) how to show Materializecss Modal programatically, via JavaScript

```
echo "<script>$('#modalWrongPassword').openModal();</script>";
```

**Note:** Make sure you include jQuery and other JS libraries only one time, e.g you have included jQuery and Materialize JS multiple times in document.